Enabling "Iterate over feature" in QGIS Graphical Modeler
There is a function in the QGIS standalone processing tools that I cannot find in the Graphical Modeler: the iterator over features.
Here is what I see in the "standalone tool" (i.e. the tool from the toolbox.

...and here is what I see in the same processing tool inside the Graphical Modeler:

Is there a way to enable this function of iteration in the Graphical Modeler ?

Use a Vector Features input type (see "Input types" for more details). When you execute the tool you can iterate over each input feature:

